# Detecting images in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I am currently creating a web app that will allow users to upload their highlights / clips from Overwatch and I wanted to use JavaScript to detect what character they were playing as.

I currently have it taking a still from the video that they upload, but wanted to use JavaScript to detect the image at the bottom left of the screen and get a result for which character it is:

[image]

I am unaware of any libraries that can do this while not over complicating my needs. Furthermore if I was to use an AI library such as tensor (which im not even sure if it would work), would I be able to use the training data if I bundled it as an app for the app store?

Answer (score 0):

If the image in the bottom left is the same, you can accomplish this using canvas.

You would need to chop the whole image down to just the avatar, and then compare the avatar to ones on file.

The comparison would require the base64 of the image, and compare those bases. If they are the same, voila!

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but I am unsure if the user was to upload an image with a different screensize if the locaiton of the avatar would be the same. where as if I used an AI it could get the general area of the bottom left side of the screen and tell me if it contains that character.

Comment: Also does the avatar move? As in turning the head or eyes?

Comment: If the screenshots were different sizes, the canvas would be different too.